# BooleanField default value not set when creating a model instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

When creating an instance of a model having a `BooleanField` `my_boolean_field` with a `default` set to `True`, I  get an error:

```
my_boolean_field is required
```

Shouldn't it be set to the default value?

**models.py**

```
class MyModel(User):

    my_boolean_field = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**admin.py**

```
class MyModelCreationForm(UserCreationForm):   

    my_boolean_field = forms.BooleanField(initial=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User

class MyModelChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    my_boolean_field = forms.BooleanField(initial=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User


class MyModelAdmin(UserAdmin):

    form = MyModelChangeForm
    add_form = MyModelCreationForm

    list_filter = ()
    list_display = ('username', 'my_boolean_field')

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'my_boolean_field', 'password' )}),
    )


    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'my_boolean_field', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        if obj==None:
            form.base_fields['username'].widget.attrs['autocomplete'] = 'off'
            form.base_fields['password1'].widget.attrs['autocomplete'] = 'off'
            form.base_fields['password2'].widget.attrs['autocomplete'] = 'off'
        return form

samsic_site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change field definition in your model form to specify `require=False`.

```
class MyModelCreationForm(UserCreationForm):   

    my_boolean_field = forms.BooleanField(initial=False, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
```

Note on [`BooleanField` reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#booleanfield)

> Note
>   Since all Field subclasses have required=True by default, the validation condition here is important. If you want to include a boolean in your form that can be either True or False (e.g. a checked or unchecked checkbox), you must remember to pass in required=False when creating the BooleanField.

Comment: Ok, I thought that if the user didn't set it, it would be set to the default value.